# how to write a shell script to input wireless connection password from my password file?

Tags: linux, shell, network-programming, wireless

in ubuntu, does it possible to write a script to read passwords from a txt file (one password per line), to try to connect to a wireless connection?

assume i know the ESSID and MAC, and the connection on my computer is eth1.

what command can i use to input password, and how to know the status?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash or whatever shell scripting :
- to read passwords from a txt file: **yes** it's possible (while read..)
- to try to connect to a wireless connection: **yes** it's possible (bring up eth *n* )

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a wlan net:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_ID key WIRELESS_KEY
```

If the key isn't hex, but ascii:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_ID key s:WIRELESS_KEY
```